# How to reach my backend API in a web host?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api

I need to access my backend API to send info from a contact form for an email, I deployed my app in a webhost called Kinghost and it gave me two urls the first is generically `mywebaddr.com:port-number` and the second is `mywebaddr.com/site`.

I have tried to use both addresses with the function route in the end just like I did in localhost, that in order to work I used http://localhost:4000/contact for example, but it didn't work...

this is my request:

```
const baseUrl = 'http://mywebsiteurl.com/contact'

const initialState = {
    message: {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        subject: '',
        main: ''
    },
}

export default class ContactUs extends Component {
    state = { ...initialState }

    reset = () =>{
        this.setState({message: initialState.message})
    }

    send = () => {

        const message = this.state.message
        const url = baseUrl
        console.log(message)
        axios.post(url, message)
            .then(this.reset())
            .then(alert('Message successfully sent!'))
    }
```

this is my index.js (backend)

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const consign = require('consign')

const port = 4005

consign()
.then('./config/middlewares.js')
.then('./api')
.then('./config/routes.js')
.into(app)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(port)
})
```

my middlewares.js contains cors

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')

module.exports = app => {
    app.use(bodyParser.json())
    app.use(cors())
}
```

Actually, I don't think it's because of my code itself once I can execute everything perfectly in localhost, but somehow I can't get through with the correct URL

I'm new to node and I can't guess what am I doing wrongly, so if someone can help me I'd be really thankful :)

Comment: Can you post the request JS code you are making, perhaps you're not catching an error. It could be CORS error, incorrect headers... Too many to guess without seeing any examples.

Comment: Ok, I have edited my question in order to provide more info!

Comment: Error messages please, we can't work with "it didnt work"

Comment: There aren't any error messages! My logs don't give me any error, the problem is that emails simply don't arrive to my mailbox

Comment: Ok, I'll try and post here my feedback

Comment: https://king.host/wiki/artigo/utilizando-o-express-no-node-js/ tried something like this?

Comment: Yeah, but it wasn't actually my problem, express was running correctly ^-^
Sorry for not replying sooner, I found the problem... The thing about Kinghost is that it gives me a port and my application needs to run on it. I adjusted the port to the given one and now my application is found by my frontend. Although it's not sending the email yet it shows me the error messages from backend in the logs... Thanks! =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a question for stack-overflow as your issue is not with the application but is with your network.
Anyhow, your API application is running on port 4005. Make sure the port is open with your hosting provider. while your at it make sure your port 4000 is open as well.

after you confirm your firewall settings ill update my answer if your still facing issues.

Comment: The port 4005 is open, but sorry for asking, why do I need to have my port 4000 open too?

Comment: because based on http://localhost:4000/contact it seems like your front end application is using port 4000

Comment: instead of const baseUrl = 'http://mywebsiteurl.com/contact' what happens when you replace your mywebsiteurl with your servers public ip example: 111.111.111.111/contact

Comment: Sorry for not replying sooner, I found the problem... The thing about Kinghost is that it gives me a port and my application needs to run on it. I adjusted the port to the given one and now my application is found by my frontend. Although it's not sending the email yet it shows me the error messages from backend in the logs... Thanks! =D

Comment: no problem. Please mark the appropriate answer as the solution :)